# Extract files from an svn repository

Tags: svn

sorry for such a basic question, but I'm new to svn and haven't had much luck with online resources.

I've got an svn repository, by which I mean a folder structure created with svnadmin, containing conf, dav, db, hooks, locks folders. I would like to extract the files in the repository to work with, as if I had checked out this repo with svn. Is there a simple way to do this? Also, this is a massive repository, so any strategy that involves less copying of files would be preferable. Thanks!

Comment: Which "online resources" gave you trouble? The official manual at http://svnbook.org/ covers this quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to extract the files in the repository to work with, as if I had checked out this repo with svn

Just **checkout** this repository, using any SVN-client. For repository on local Filesystem you can use ordinary client and the same commands as for remote repository, just use `file:///` protocol and different URL.

For repository, created in `Z:\repo` (Win-world), it's URL will be `file:///Z:/Repo` and you can `svn co` this URL

```
z:\Repo>dir /B
locks
hooks
conf
README.txt
db
format
svn.ico

>svn ls -R -v file:///Z:/Repo
      1 Badger                июн 09 22:59 ./
      1 Badger                июн 09 22:59 branches/
      1 Badger                июн 09 22:59 tags/
      1 Badger                июн 09 22:59 trunk/
```